# Linked list insertion in Dafny

Tags: dafny

After following Rustan Leino's paper, I was able to [complete](https://github.com/CodeNinja89/dafnyPractice/blob/main/LinkedQueue_krml.dfy)  the verification of a linked queue. Now, I'm trying to implement a more general insertion in queue, i.e., instead of appending a node, we insert a node at a given position.

After referring a few SO posts, I have come up with the following code:

```
class Node {
    var data: int
    var next: Node?
    
    ghost var footprint: set<object>
    ghost var contents: seq<int>
    
    ghost predicate valid()
        reads this, footprint
    {
        this in footprint &&
        (next != null ==> next in footprint &&
            next.footprint <= footprint &&
            this !in next.footprint &&
            next.valid()) &&
        (next == null ==> |contents| == 0 &&
            next != null ==> next.contents == contents[1..])
    }
    
    constructor()
        modifies this
        ensures valid() && fresh(footprint - {this})
        ensures next == null
        ensures |contents| == 0
    {
        next := null;
        contents := [];
        footprint := {this}
    }
    
    method enqueueMid(d: int, pos: int)
        requires valid()
        requires 0 <= pos <= |contents|
        modifies footprint
        enures valid() && fresh(footprint - old(footprint))
    {
        var i: int := 0;
        var curr := this;
        
        while(i < pos && curr.next != null)
            invariant curr != null
            invariant curr != null ==> curr.valid()
            decreases if curr != null then curr.footprint else {}
        {
            i := i + 1;
            curr := curr.next;
        }
        
        var n := new Node();
        n.data := d;
        
        if(curr == null) {
            curr := n;
            contents := contents + [d]; // if current is null then we have reached the end of the list!
        } else {
            n.next := curr.next;
            n.footprint := curr.footprint - {curr}; // acyclicity!
            curr.footprint := curr.footprint + n.footprint;
            curr.next := n;
            contents := contents[ .. pos] + [d] + contents[pos ..];
        }
        
        footprint := footprint + n.footprint;
        assert(valid()); // error: could not prove: next in footprint. could not prove: next.valid()
    }
}
```

The final assertion gives me errors.I think the valid predicate is not well formed. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172163/while-loop-termination-with-null-references-in-dafny-linked-list-implementation) SO question to frame my predicate and also the while loop. Moreover, I think, I have to reason about how `contents` is updated. I cannot figure that out though.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is lots of errors in above code for example - `var curr: int := this;`. Please fix these.

Comment: After fixing these. I am able to get Dafny verify successfully (I am using dafny 4.4.0)

Comment: I resolved the syntax errors in the code and updated the question. I still cannot get Dafny to verify. I still get the same error. I'm using the same version of Dafny (4.4.0).

Comment: Right, I don't think it verifies for me too. (I might have done something wrong previously).

Comment: I'm trying to hack the example from Leino's paper to implement this. I'll ask another question after implementing something.

Comment: I think this involves proving lots of additional lemmas. For example see this - https://github.com/jorge-jbs/adt-verification-dafny/blob/JLAMP22/src/linear/layer4/SinglyLinkedList.dfy which does same things in `Insert` but instead of pos It takes node.

Comment: Definitely not first thing to try if you are learning dafny. In particular you have to roll back to head again fixing footprint and contents of each node in path and show to dafny that fix is valid.

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing. In Leino's example, this is trivial because the footprint of the node that is inserted is not updated. It is always `{this}`. So a simple `forall` suffices. But in my case, the footprint is updated and then we have to account for the footprints of all the previous nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost solution (I am using one assumption).

One of major problem I see in your approach is you are only updating footprint and contents of node just before node to be inserted. But this will invalid all previous nodes contents and footprint invariant. That is what I meant when I said (in comments) that you need to roll back to head again fixing footprint and contents of each previous nodes. I have made some small changes in my solution regarding `pos` precondition and `valid` predicate.

```
class Node {
  var data: int
  var next: Node?

  ghost var contents: seq<int>
  ghost var footprint: set<object>

  ghost predicate valid()
    decreases footprint
    reads this, footprint
  {
     this in footprint &&
     (next != null ==> (next in footprint && next.footprint < footprint && this !in next.footprint)) &&
     (next != null ==> next.valid()) &&
     (next != null ==> contents == [data] + next.contents) &&
     (next == null ==> contents == [data])
  }

  constructor (d: int)
    ensures valid()
    ensures data == d && next == null
  {
     data, next := d, null;
     footprint, contents := {this}, [data];
  }

  method insert(pos: int, d: int)
    requires valid()
    modifies footprint
    requires 0 <= pos < |contents|
    ensures valid()
  {
     var i := 0;
     var curr := this;

     ghost var nodes := [curr];

     while i < pos && curr.next != null
      invariant curr != null
      invariant 1 <= |nodes| && nodes[|nodes|-1] == curr
      invariant curr.valid()
      invariant nodes[0] == this
      invariant curr.footprint <= footprint
      invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < |nodes| ==> nodes[j] != null && nodes[j].valid() && nodes[j] in footprint
      invariant forall j :: 1 <= j < |nodes| ==> nodes[j] == nodes[j-1].next && nodes[j-1] !in nodes[j].footprint
     {
        i, curr := i + 1, curr.next;
        assert curr.valid();
        nodes := nodes + [curr];
     }

     var nn := new Node(d);
     nn.next := curr.next;
     if curr.next != null {
       nn.footprint, nn.contents := {nn} + curr.next.footprint, [d] + curr.next.contents;
     }
     assert nn.valid();
     assert curr in footprint;
     curr.next := nn;
     assert nn in curr.next.footprint;

     var j := |nodes|-1;
     assert nodes[j].next == nn;
     assert nodes[j].next.valid();

     while j >= 0
       invariant 0 <= j < |nodes|
       invariant nodes[0] == this
       invariant forall k : int :: 0 <= j <= k < |nodes| ==> nodes[k].next != null && nodes[k].next.valid()
       invariant forall k : int :: 0 <= j < k < |nodes| ==> nodes[k].valid()
     {
        nodes[j].footprint := {nodes[j]} + nodes[j].next.footprint;
        assert nodes[j].next in nodes[j].next.footprint;
        assert nodes[j] in nodes[j].footprint;
        assume nodes[j].footprint < nodes[j].next.footprint;
        nodes[j].contents := [nodes[j].data] + nodes[j].next.contents;
        j := j - 1;
     }
     assert nodes[0].valid();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, my laptop is at the university so I cannot try this but I'll do it over the weekend. Anyway, the link you shared in the comments, I was already reading that paper. The BS Thesis (and a paper) by Blasquez has pointed out some problems that I already knew about. For instance, all the nodes before the inserted node are invalidated. He has a cool solution that removes the need of a `tailContents` from the `Node` class as used in Leino's paper. This makes updates easier.

Comment: the paper by Blasquez: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352220823000299.

Comment: Sounds good. Sorry I missed linking paper earlier should have done that

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. I'll study this. Many thanks for your help!